# How to set date & time informations in entity class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm working on a spring boot project nowadays. And I totally love it.
I've created my services, entities, repos. Everything seems ok for simple scenarios.

But the thing is , one of my entities has attributes(properties) as follows:

- userID;
- loginName;
- email;
- profiles;
- createdDate;
- lastModifiedDate;

I'm listing my services on swagger ui. When I try to call update service on swagger, lastModifiedDate criteria shouldn't be listed as an input property, I need to handle this property on the back end. Likewise, when I try to add a new user record from swagger, createdDate criteria shouldn't be listed as an input property, I need to handle this property on the back end.

I try to google this, but I couldn't find a relative answer so far. 
Do you have any recommendations ? Any links, documents. . .
Or is it even possible ?

screenshots from swagger-ui :

https://ibb.co/QMWDLjR

https://ibb.co/yqqQWyG

Comment: Can you try adding the Jackson annotation `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)` to these properties. From what I can see these should be rejected when the docs are generated.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good practice to separate `entity` and `api resonse` object. That way you can choose what fields to expose to api contract.

So in your case, create a new object without modifedOn and createdOn and use that in your controller

Comment: But it changes dynamically (api properties) , like I said in the description. Is it still possible ? I couldn't figure out in my mind.

Comment: sorry i couldn't find in description. What changes dynamically ?

Comment: imagine that there are 2 services for creating a new user and updating an existing user. on create service, the createdDate attribute should be invisible on swagger (I need to handle on back end),  on update service , the lastModifiedDate property should be invisible on swagger ui, I need to handle this information on back end.

Comment: Then you will have to create different POJO for create and update apis :)
Out of curiousity, why would you want to make createdOn as input param for update. Shouldn't that be immutable ?

Comment: Good question :) I have a case study for a job application. And they're very strict about holding these datas in this way in this case study.